Xcode - Swift - Integrating Stripe VIA Cocoapod
I Created a brand new project.
I hit pod init, and change pod file content to below
target 'CardScannerViaPodUIKit' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for CardScannerViaPodUIKit
  pod 'Stripe', '~> 23.29'

end

And hit pod install, pod installed successfully. But build fails.
Build Error: some files could not be transferred (code 23)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I deleted derived data / Created 2 new projects (both SwiftUI and UIKit based) and did above exercise. But build is failing always.
Please help.
Whereas its working well if I integrate stripe VIA SPM. But for some reason, i can't use SPM.

Full error message maybe? I guess you opened correctly the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj

yes i opened the workspace.

The most common solution I see to this is to make sure you're using the latest version of Cocoapods. (you don't mention in the question which version you use).

Error Details
CardScannerViaPod2.app/Frameworks/Stripe.framework/StripeBundle.bundle" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
CardScannerViaPod2.app/Frameworks/Stripe.framework/_CodeSignature" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
CardScannerViaPod2.app/Frameworks/Stripe.framework/.Info.plist.0TypTj" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
CardScannerViaPod2.app/Frameworks/Stripe.framework/.Stripe.DFrfQi" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

I m using cocoapods-1.13.  New version is 1.15. Will updating this help?

"Operation not permitted" is a different type of error and probably means something is unusual with your project directory permissions

I solved by doing this
build setting -> ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = no

Feel free to edit your question with the full error message emphasing  on "Operation not permitted" + "framework" build (to no conflict with CocoaPods "fetching" issue) and answer with the fix or mark your question as duplicate.
